# Camera Preview performance issue on some devices

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I am creating a camera application using android camera api by this example:  https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/camera-hardware/android-camera-example/

I made some changes according to my needs and you can see the code below. The problem is, camera preview for back camera works quite fine on my LG G3 device but on LG G4 it gets too slow. It also works fine with front camera on both devices.

What can cause this problem ?

**CameraPreview:**

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private static String TAG = "CameraPreview";

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
private Size mPreviewSize;


public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera){
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try{
        Log.d(TAG, "Surface Created..");
        if(mCamera == null){
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }
    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }
    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    // start preview with new settings
    setCamera(camera);
    try {
        Log.d(TAG,"RefreshCamera..");
        if(mCamera == null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Camera null");
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Surface Changed..");


    refreshCamera(mCamera);
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    //method to set a camera instance
    mCamera = camera;
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

     mCamera.release();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onMeasure..");
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    if(mSupportedPreviewSizes==null){
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }else{

        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        Log.d(TAG, "mPreviewSize set.. Width: " + mPreviewSize.width+" Height: " + mPreviewSize.height);
    }
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

}

I can share the Activity class if its needed..

Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem using surface view .use the below preview class.its working for me for all the device screen.

public class SquareCameraPreview extends SurfaceView {

```
public static final String TAG = SquareCameraPreview.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

private static final int ZOOM_OUT = 0;
private static final int ZOOM_IN = 1;
private static final int ZOOM_DELTA = 1;

private static final int FOCUS_SQR_SIZE = 100;
private static final int FOCUS_MAX_BOUND = 1000;
private static final int FOCUS_MIN_BOUND = -FOCUS_MAX_BOUND;

private static final double ASPECT_RATIO = 3.0 / 4.0;
private Camera mCamera;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;

// For scaling
private int mMaxZoom;
private boolean mIsZoomSupported;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
private int mScaleFactor = 1;
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

// For focus
private boolean mIsFocus;
private boolean mIsFocusReady;
private Camera.Area mFocusArea;
private ArrayList<Camera.Area> mFocusAreas;

public SquareCameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public SquareCameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public SquareCameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    mFocusArea = new Camera.Area(new Rect(), 1000);
    mFocusAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
    mFocusAreas.add(mFocusArea);
}

/**
 * Measure the view and its content to determine the measured width and the
 * measured height
 */
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    final boolean isPortrait =
            getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    if (isPortrait) {
        if (width > height * ASPECT_RATIO) {
            width = (int) (height * ASPECT_RATIO + 0.5);
        } else {
            height = (int) (width / ASPECT_RATIO + 0.5);
        }
    } else {
        if (height > width * ASPECT_RATIO) {
            height = (int) (width * ASPECT_RATIO + 0.5);
        } else {
            width = (int) (height / ASPECT_RATIO + 0.5);
        }
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

public int getViewWidth() {
    return getWidth();
}

public int getViewHeight() {
    return getHeight();
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;

    if (camera != null) {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        mIsZoomSupported = params.isZoomSupported();
        if (mIsZoomSupported) {
            mMaxZoom = params.getMaxZoom();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    final int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            mIsFocus = true;

            mLastTouchX = event.getX();
            mLastTouchY = event.getY();

            mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            if (mIsFocus && mIsFocusReady) {
                handleFocus(mCamera.getParameters());
            }
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
            mIsFocus = false;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private void handleZoom(Camera.Parameters params) {
    int zoom = params.getZoom();
    if (mScaleFactor == ZOOM_IN) {
        if (zoom < mMaxZoom) zoom += ZOOM_DELTA;
    } else if (mScaleFactor == ZOOM_OUT) {
        if (zoom > 0) zoom -= ZOOM_DELTA;
    }
    params.setZoom(zoom);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

private void handleFocus(Camera.Parameters params) {
    float x = mLastTouchX;
    float y = mLastTouchY;

    if (!setFocusBound(x, y)) return;

    List<String> supportedFocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (supportedFocusModes != null
            && supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
        Log.d(TAG, mFocusAreas.size() + "");
        params.setFocusAreas(mFocusAreas);
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                // Callback when the auto focus completes
            }
        });
    }
}

public void setIsFocusReady(final boolean isFocusReady) {
    mIsFocusReady = isFocusReady;
}

private boolean setFocusBound(float x, float y) {
    int left = (int) (x - FOCUS_SQR_SIZE / 2);
    int right = (int) (x + FOCUS_SQR_SIZE / 2);
    int top = (int) (y - FOCUS_SQR_SIZE / 2);
    int bottom = (int) (y + FOCUS_SQR_SIZE / 2);

    if (FOCUS_MIN_BOUND > left || left > FOCUS_MAX_BOUND) return false;
    if (FOCUS_MIN_BOUND > right || right > FOCUS_MAX_BOUND) return false;
    if (FOCUS_MIN_BOUND > top || top > FOCUS_MAX_BOUND) return false;
    if (FOCUS_MIN_BOUND > bottom || bottom > FOCUS_MAX_BOUND) return false;

    mFocusArea.rect.set(left, top, right, bottom);

    return true;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor = (int) detector.getScaleFactor();
        handleZoom(mCamera.getParameters());
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

> public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PictureCallback {

```
public static int HIGH_RESOLUTION_WIDTH=1000;
public static int HIGH_RESOLUTION_HIGHT=1500;
public static String clorie_count;
private long startTime = 0L;

public static final String TAG = CameraFragment.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String CAMERA_ID_KEY = "camera_id";
public static final String CAMERA_FLASH_KEY = "flash_mode";
public static final String IMAGE_INFO = "image_info";

private static final int PICTURE_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH = 1280;
private static final int PREVIEW_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH = 640;

private int mCameraID;
private String mFlashMode;
private Camera mCamera;
private SquareCameraPreview mPreviewView;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

private boolean mIsSafeToTakePhoto = false;

private ImageParameters mImageParameters;

private CameraOrientationListener mOrientationListener;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = activity;
    mOrientationListener = new CameraOrientationListener(context);
}

View view;
Dialog listDialog;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mCameraID = getBackCameraID();
            mFlashMode = CameraSettingPreferences.getCameraFlashMode(getActivity());
            mImageParameters = new ImageParameters();
        } else {
            mCameraID = savedInstanceState.getInt(CAMERA_ID_KEY);
            mFlashMode = savedInstanceState.getString(CAMERA_FLASH_KEY);
            mImageParameters = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(IMAGE_INFO);
        }
   mPreviewView = (SquareCameraPreview) view.findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
         mPreviewView.getHolder().addCallback(CameraFragment.this);
         mImageParameters.mIsPortrait =getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

         capture_icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            takePicture();
        }
    });
return view;
}
         private void takePicture() {

            if (mIsSafeToTakePhoto) {
                setSafeToTakePhoto(false);

                mOrientationListener.rememberOrientation();

                // Shutter callback occurs after the image is captured. This can
                // be used to trigger a sound to let the user know that image is taken
                Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = null;

                // Raw callback occurs when the raw image data is available
                Camera.PictureCallback raw = null;

                // postView callback occurs when a scaled, fully processed
                // postView image is available.
                Camera.PictureCallback postView = null;

                // jpeg callback occurs when the compressed image is available
                mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, raw, postView, this);
            }
        }        

        private void setSafeToTakePhoto(final boolean isSafeToTakePhoto) {
        mIsSafeToTakePhoto = isSafeToTakePhoto;
    }

    private void setCameraFocusReady(final boolean isFocusReady) {
        if (this.mPreviewView != null) {
            mPreviewView.setIsFocusReady(isFocusReady);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Determine the current display orientation and rotate the camera preview
     * accordingly
     */
    private void determineDisplayOrientation() {
        CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraID, cameraInfo);

        // Clockwise rotation needed to align the window display to the natural position
        int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;

        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0: {
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            }
            case Surface.ROTATION_90: {
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            }
            case Surface.ROTATION_180: {
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            }
            case Surface.ROTATION_270: {
                degrees = 270;
                break;
            }
        }

        int displayOrientation;

        // CameraInfo.Orientation is the angle relative to the natural position of the device
        // in clockwise rotation (angle that is rotated clockwise from the natural position)
        if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            // Orientation is angle of rotation when facing the camera for
            // the camera image to match the natural orientation of the device
            displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            displayOrientation = (360 - displayOrientation) % 360;
        } else {
            displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        mImageParameters.mDisplayOrientation = displayOrientation;
        mImageParameters.mLayoutOrientation = degrees;

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(mImageParameters.mDisplayOrientation);
    }
    private void setupCamera() {
        // Never keep a global parameters
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        Size bestPreviewSize = determineBestPreviewSize(parameters);
        Size bestPictureSize = determineBestPictureSize(parameters);

        parameters.setPreviewSize(bestPreviewSize.width, bestPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(bestPictureSize.width, bestPictureSize.height);


        // Set continuous picture focus, if it's supported
        if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        }

        final View changeCameraFlashModeBtn = getView().findViewById(R.id.flash);
        List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (flashModes != null && flashModes.contains(mFlashMode)) {
            parameters.setFlashMode(mFlashMode);
            changeCameraFlashModeBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            changeCameraFlashModeBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        // Lock in the changes
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }
    private Size determineBestPreviewSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        return determineBestSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), PREVIEW_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH);
    }

    private Size determineBestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        return determineBestSize(parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes(), PICTURE_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH);
    }

    private Size determineBestSize(List<Size> sizes, int widthThreshold) {
        Size bestSize = null;
        Size size;
        int numOfSizes = sizes.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfSizes; i++) {
            size = sizes.get(i);
            boolean isDesireRatio = (size.width / 4) == (size.height / 3);
            boolean isBetterSize = (bestSize == null) || size.width > bestSize.width;

            if (isDesireRatio && isBetterSize) {
                bestSize = size;
            }
        }

        if (bestSize == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "cannot find the best camera size");
            return sizes.get(sizes.size() - 1);
        }

        return bestSize;
    }

     /**
     * Start the camera preview
     */
    private void startCameraPreview() {
        determineDisplayOrientation();
        setupCamera();

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            setSafeToTakePhoto(true);
            setCameraFocusReady(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't start camera preview due to IOException " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getCamera(int cameraID) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open(cameraID);
            mPreviewView.setCamera(mCamera);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't open camera with id " + cameraID);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        HERE YOU GET THE PHOTO BYTE[] arg0

        CONVERT IT TO BITMAP OR STROE INTO A FILE


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mSurfaceHolder = holder;

            getCamera(mCameraID);
            startCameraPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 



        private static class CameraOrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener {

            private int mCurrentNormalizedOrientation;
            private int mRememberedNormalOrientation;

            public CameraOrientationListener(Context context) {
                super(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                if (orientation != ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
                    mCurrentNormalizedOrientation = normalize(orientation);
                }
            }

            /**
             * @param degrees Amount of clockwise rotation from the device's natural position
             * @return Normalized degrees to just 0, 90, 180, 270
             */
            private int normalize(int degrees) {
                if (degrees > 315 || degrees <= 45) {
                    return 0;
                }

                if (degrees > 45 && degrees <= 135) {
                    return 90;
                }

                if (degrees > 135 && degrees <= 225) {
                    return 180;
                }

                if (degrees > 225 && degrees <= 315) {
                    return 270;
                }

                throw new RuntimeException("The physics as we know them are no more. Watch out for anomalies.");
            }

            public void rememberOrientation() {
                mRememberedNormalOrientation = mCurrentNormalizedOrientation;
            }

            public int getRememberedNormalOrientation() {
                rememberOrientation();
                return mRememberedNormalOrientation;
            }
        }
        /*@Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            if (mCamera == null) {
                restartPreview();
            }
        }*/

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            mOrientationListener.disable();

            // stop the preview
            if (mCamera != null) {
                stopCameraPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
            if (getKillStatus()) {
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
           // CameraSettingPreferences.saveCameraFlashMode(getActivity(), mFlashMode);

            super.onStop();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            /*if (camera != null) {
                camera.stopPreview();
                preview.setupCamera(null,isResolutionHigh);
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }

            int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            if (numCams > 0) {
                try {
                    camera = Camera.open(0);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    preview.setupCamera(camera,isResolutionHigh);

                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    // Toast.makeText(ctx, getString(R.string.camera_not_found),
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }*/
            if (mCamera == null) {
                restartPreview();
            }

        }
        private void restartPreview() {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                stopCameraPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }

            getCamera(mCameraID);
            startCameraPreview();
        }
        /**
         * Stop the camera preview
         */
        private void stopCameraPreview() {
            setSafeToTakePhoto(false);
            setCameraFocusReady(false);

            // Nulls out callbacks, stops face detection
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mPreviewView.setCamera(null);
        }
        private int getBackCameraID() {
            return CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        }

}
```

> AND YOUR XML FILE

```html
<com.demo.camera.SquareCameraPreview
        android:id="@+id/camerapreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

ImageParameter Class

```html
public class ImageParameters implements Parcelable {

    public boolean mIsPortrait;

    public int mDisplayOrientation;
    public int mLayoutOrientation;

    public int mCoverHeight, mCoverWidth;
    public int mPreviewHeight, mPreviewWidth;

    public ImageParameters(Parcel in) {
        mIsPortrait = (in.readByte() == 1);

        mDisplayOrientation = in.readInt();
        mLayoutOrientation = in.readInt();

        mCoverHeight = in.readInt();
        mCoverWidth = in.readInt();
        mPreviewHeight = in.readInt();
        mPreviewWidth = in.readInt();
    }

    public ImageParameters() {}

    public int calculateCoverWidthHeight() {
       return Math.abs(mPreviewHeight - mPreviewWidth) / 2;
    }

    public int getAnimationParameter() {
        return mIsPortrait ? mCoverHeight : mCoverWidth;
    }

    public boolean isPortrait() {
        return mIsPortrait;
    }

    public ImageParameters createCopy() {
        ImageParameters imageParameters = new ImageParameters();

        imageParameters.mIsPortrait = mIsPortrait;
        imageParameters.mDisplayOrientation = mDisplayOrientation;
        imageParameters.mLayoutOrientation = mLayoutOrientation;

        imageParameters.mCoverHeight = mCoverHeight;
        imageParameters.mCoverWidth = mCoverWidth;
        imageParameters.mPreviewHeight = mPreviewHeight;
        imageParameters.mPreviewWidth = mPreviewWidth;

        return imageParameters;
    }

    public String getStringValues() {
        return "is Portrait: " + mIsPortrait + "," +
                "\ncover height: " + mCoverHeight + " width: " + mCoverWidth
                + "\npreview height: " + mPreviewHeight + " width: " + mPreviewWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (mIsPortrait ? 1 : 0));

        dest.writeInt(mDisplayOrientation);
        dest.writeInt(mLayoutOrientation);

        dest.writeInt(mCoverHeight);
        dest.writeInt(mCoverWidth);
        dest.writeInt(mPreviewHeight);
        dest.writeInt(mPreviewWidth);
    }

    public static final Creator<ImageParameters> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ImageParameters>() {
        @Override
        public ImageParameters createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ImageParameters(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ImageParameters[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ImageParameters[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Another class you need camera setting preference

```html
public class CameraSettingPreferences {

    private static final String FLASH_MODE = "squarecamera__flash_mode";

    private static SharedPreferences getCameraSettingPreferences(@NonNull final Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("com.desmond.squarecamera", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    protected static void saveCameraFlashMode(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final String cameraFlashMode) {
        final SharedPreferences preferences = getCameraSettingPreferences(context);

        if (preferences != null) {
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString(FLASH_MODE, cameraFlashMode);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }

    public static String getCameraFlashMode(@NonNull final Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences preferences = getCameraSettingPreferences(context);

        if (preferences != null) {
            return preferences.getString(FLASH_MODE, Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
        }

        return Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I couldn't use it at all. Can I have a walkthrough ?

Comment: are you need activity class where to use it?

Comment: @BatuhanCoşkun..i have added all the needed document..try this and let me know.

Comment: I think i will need the ImageParameters class also. Thanks again for the help though

Comment: I made it work finally thanks to your effort. But problem is still the same. Preview is not smooth enough. And the problem is only with the G4 device and on the back facing camera.. Maybe it is device spesific or because Im using the old camera API and the device has Android 6.0. I will try with another 6.0 device. Thanks for the help again..